# Share Document Root for Apache w/ SSL with two separate subdomains and certs

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

So, I'm running an Apache server on CentOS 7. I have two domains pointing to the same place: https://www.example.com and https://example.com. In my cfg, I have three `VirtualHosts`; one for http (for both) one for the subdomain-less, and one for the www. I have the separate certs configured (one for each), but when I deploy, Apache just serves up the first cert it finds in the cfg. So if I have the `VirtualHost` for www first, it serves up the www cert for both https://example.com and https://www.example.com

I have other domains being served on the same box and they get all the right certs.

Can somebody please explain what is going on here? It's driving me absolutely

```
# Abbreviated Main config file for example.com domain
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias example.com  

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You've repeatedly used `ServerAlias` where you should have used `ServerName`.

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that any of your virtual hosts have `ServerName` defined. Apache won't use a virtual host that doesn't have this defined, even if they have a `ServerAlias`.